# "unable to open the database file" error in Flex for Android

Tags: android, apache-flex, sqlite, air

Using Flex 4.5 for Android development, this is the script that should create the database:

```
private var db:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("events.db");
        private var conn:SQLConnection;

        public function MyDB() {
            conn = new SQLConnection();
            conn.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler);
            conn.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
            conn.open(db, );
        }
```

and I have added this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but I get this error:

```
SQLError: 'Error #3125: Unable to open the database file.', details:'Connection closed.', operation:'open', detailID:'1001'
    at flash.data::SQLConnection/internalOpen()
    at flash.data::SQLConnection/open()
    at com.galleons.util::MyDB()[/Users/luca/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/Galleons/src/com/galleons/util/MyDB.as:24]
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but anyway I was facing the same error and found the cause. If any of the parent directories of File which you pass to `SQLConnection.open()` does not exist, Flash Player throws an `Error` with `detailID=1001`. Simply call `dbFile.parent.createDirectory()` and the error should be gone.

Similar answer was given on Adobe Forums: [SQLError #3125](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/578840)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the 'usual suspects'?

- file exists
- not locked by some other app / stale version of your app
- path is correct

Comment: file doesn't exists! That's the point, the app should be creating it.. if I create manually the file then it works, but read only. It is a permission problem I think, but I gave the app permission to WRITE TO EXTERNAL STORAGE..

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use 'applicationStorageDirectory' or 'documentsDirectory'? Also - what's with the trailing ',' in the 'open' call?

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem is due to mixing the SQLConnection class's open() method – which is synchronous – with events that are only supposed to be used when opening an asynchronous connection. You would open an asynchronous connection by using the openAsync() method instead of the open() method.

The docs are contradictory in this matter because it is, in fact, possible to listen for SQLEvent.OPEN when opening a synchronous connection. However, notice that the SQLErrorEvent.ERROR listener is not being triggered in your code and you are instead getting a runtime error. The docs make no mention of SQLErrorEvent.ERROR working with a synchronous connection; that does appear to be the case.

It's possible this is an AIR bug, but I suspect mixing synchronous methods with asynchronous event listeners is just a gray area. It's also likely that the problem could be solved if you instead wrap the open() call in a try/catch block, which is the recommended way to catch synchronous errors:

```
try
{ 
    conn.open(db); 
    trace("Hey, is that a database?", (db.exists));
}
catch (err:SQLError) 
{ 
    trace("Error, database not created:", err.message); 
    trace("Error details:", err.details); 
}
```